# Service doesn't implement Property's get/set method

Tags: c#, silverlight, service, properties

I'm having trouble with the Service Reference Manager in my Silverlight application substituting the get and set methods of a property with a generic one.

My example: I have a Rule class in my Service that has three public properties that all use the same private member.

```
[DataContract]
public class RulesReadable
{
    [DataMember]
    private bool? m_passed;

    ...

    [DataMember]
    public bool? State
    {
        get { return m_passed; }
        set { m_passed = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public bool HasPassed
    {
        get { return (m_passed == true) ? true : false; }
        set { m_passed = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public bool HasFailed
    {
        get { return (m_passed == false) ? true : false; }
        set { m_passed = !value; }
    }
}
```

When I call the service, get this data type back, and try to get/set the properties I find that each property has been given its own variable instead of sharing one between the three. If I go to the definition of the class on the Silverlight side I see that this is in fact what has happened:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Manager.RulesReadable", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWebApp.Services")]
public partial class ManagerRulesReadable : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private bool HasFailedField;

    ...

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public bool HasFailed {
        get {
            return this.HasFailedField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.HasFailedField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.HasFailedField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("HasFailed");
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

How do I get the class on the Silverlight side to behave like the class on the Service side?

Answer (score 0):

First add the assemblies that these classes are in as references to your Silverlight project.  When creating your service reference select the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" checkbox and either reuse *all* referenced assemblies or pick and choose specific assemblies to reuse.  The assemblies that are referenced by the service directly (and any dependencies) will then be a part of the Silverlight application as well.

Comment: I looked at it and "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" is already selected.

Comment: Is the "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" above it checked? You may need to remove and re-add the reference to rebuild it using the referenced assemblies.  Note that the namespace will likely change so you will have to go in and modify the usages.

Comment: Ok, I don't know that I'm adding the assembly to my Silverlight project like you say to. The closest I got was to add a code file as a link since I don't think I can add non-Silverlight assemblies to a  Silverlight project (http://forums.silverlight.net/post/150999.aspx). After I linked the file, I deleted and recreated my ServiceReference in Silverlight, but I'm still having the same issues.

Comment: Have you unified the namespaces between the two projects? See here: http://10rem.net/blog/2009/07/13/sharing-entities-between-wcf-and-silverlight

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Service References.  They are evil.  If you google "Silverlight WCF without Service Reference" you will find several good tutorials.